# Apache - CXF jaxrs-server - unable to hit the resource which is defined first in jaxrs-server endpoint

Tags: apache, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I'm using Apache-CXF for JAX-RS implementation. I have two resources which are defined in two bean. My jaxrs-server in context.xml os as follow

```
 <jaxrs:server id="serverId" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean id="bean1" class="com.Bean1" />
        <bean id="bean2" class="com.Bean2" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Interface for Bean1 is as follows -

```
   @Path("/")
   public interface IBean1 {
    @GET
    @Path("/beaninfo1")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response checkBean1();
   }
```

Interface for Bean2 is as follows -

```
   @Path("/")
   public interface IBean2 {
    @GET
    @Path("/beaninfo2")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response checkBean1();
   }
```

I'm unable to hit the resource which is defined in last in serviceBans definition. In this case i'm able to hit Bean2 but not Bean1, getting 404 error, where as if i put Bean2 first and then Bean1, i'm able to hit Bean1 only.

Is there anything wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Give them different `@Path` annotations at the class level.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to keep the same path at class level. Is there any other way to handle this ?

Comment: As you suggested, I managed with having different @Path annotation at class level and it worked. It seems, we can't have the same path at class level.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have the same `@Path` annotation at class level. You need to use a resourcecomparator. Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725770/multiple-resoucebean-configuration-in-cxf-using-spring)