# How to configure multiple webservices using applicationContext.xml and CXF

Tags: spring, cxf

I have a applicationContext.xml in which I am configuring all my webservices like below -

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="bookService" />
        <ref bean="movieService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>


<bean id="bookService" class="com.informit.apachecxfexample.BookServiceImpl"/> 
<bean id="movieService" class="com.informit.apachecxfexample.MovieServiceImpl"/>
```

However only the first service (bookService) can be called . If I change the order of reference bean to

```
<ref bean="movieService" />
<ref bean="bookService" />
```

in the above case only movieService is called .

Is there a way of calling all the services configured in applicationContext.xml ?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725770/multiple-resoucebean-configuration-in-cxf-using-spring